# run onchange and onload in the same function

Tags: jquery, onchange, onload

I have this following script:

```
$(function user_type(){

    /* Change select box  values */
    $(document).on("change",".user_type",function(){
        var user_type = $(this).data('user_type');

        $.post(base_url+"index.php/manage/load_type",{user_type: user_type},function(data){

            var data_obj = JSON.parse(data);

 $('#yehida').empty().append('please choose');
 switch (user_type) {
    case 1:
        $.each(data_obj, function (i, item) {
            $('#yehida').append($('<option>', { 
                value: 0,
                text : 'no records'
            }));
        });
        break;
    case 2:
        $.each(data_obj, function (i, item) {
            $('#yehida').append($('<option>', { 
                value: item['id'],
                text : item['department_name']
            }));
        });
        break;

}
```

This script works only onchange. I want it to run also when the page is loaded.
What do i need to add\change?

Comment: may be wrap your code in a function and call the function in on document ready and change event..!

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract out the logic of the handler to its own function. You can then call it on load and on select change. Try this:

```
function foo() {
    var user_type = $(this).data('user_type');
    $.post(base_url + "index.php/manage/load_type", {
        user_type: user_type
    }, function (data) {
        var data_obj = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#yehida').empty().append('please choose');
        switch (user_type) {
            case 1:
                $.each(data_obj, function (i, item) {
                    $('#yehida').append($('<option>', {
                        value: 0,
                        text: 'no records'
                    }));
                });
                break;
            case 2:
                $.each(data_obj, function (i, item) {
                    $('#yehida').append($('<option>', {
                        value: item['id'],
                        text: item['department_name']
                    }));
                });
                break;
        }
    })
}

/* Change select box  values */
$(document).on("change", ".user_type", foo)

/* on load */
$.proxy(foo, $('.user_type'))();
```

Note that `$.proxy` is required on the load call to maintain the scope of `this` within the function.

Comment: 10x Rory. But the type `user_type` always get the same value.
how do i edit the value so the onload function will give me another value each time it loads?